# gboost implementation error in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

Hi im trying to implement gboost library in matlab the input format is a cell array 'G(1,n)' of n graph structures in this format g.nodelables (n,1) [L1;L2;..Ln] , g.edges (m,2) [e1_from e1_to ; ... em_from em_to]

i used the following code and get the error below:

> > G.nodelabels =['a';'b';'c']
> >
> > G.edges =[1 2;1 3 ;2 3]
> >
> > P.nodelabels =['d';'e';'f']
> >
> > P.edges =[1 2 ;1 3 ;2 3]
> >
> > s ={G,P}

s =

```
[1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]
```

> > gspan(s,2)

Starting normal gspan run...
**Undefined function or variable "subg".
Error in gspan (line 124)
for i=1:length(subg)**

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !! To create a cell array of 'n' graph structures :
The code below creates a cell array 'G' with two structure arrays with two labels called "edges" and "nodelabels".

`G{1,1}.edges =[1 2;1 3; 2 3]

    G{1,1}.nodelabels =[6;6;6]

    G{1,2}.nodelabels =[7;6;8]

    G{1,2}.edges =[1 2;1 3; 2 3]`